# Backbone routing binded, but fires twice

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var router = new dummy();

router.bind('all', function(route) {
    document.write('triggered: ' + route + '<br/>');
});
```

I have a query on the above code...I have done the above part successfully, but it fires 2 times in my all navigation...first one gives correct info, second blank always...any idea???

Answer (score 2):

It happens because Backbone fires it twice:

```
router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
router.trigger('route', name, args);
```

So you can just listen for the `route` instead of `all`